# Failed to apply patch while updating android studio 3.5

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu-18.04, android-studio-3.5

I'm getting an error while updating android studio from 3.4.2 to 3.5, how can I resolve the problem?

See the image for the error message.[image: android studio 3.5 patch failed]

If I download new android studio 3.5 then it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this happened due to the mismatch of Java.exe in following two directories:

- `Android_Studio/jre/jre/bin/` and `Android_Studio/jre/bin/`

**Solution:**
Copy the Java.exe file from **`Android_Studio/jre/jre/bin/`** and replace the one located in **`Android_Studio/jre/bin/`**